# How can I retrieve all comments from a post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In this [public sandbox group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/161819063969990/) I created a post and added 55 comments on it.

Then I [tested in the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=161819063969990_265261610292401/comments?limit=2) (limit 2 just to make it easier to see the results).

The problem is that [there is a `next` entry indicating that there are more results.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) But if I click it, it does not show me the next page, instead some odd behavior occurs.

Then after that if I click `previous` it show me the last page, skipping everything in the middle. If I click `previous` again, it still shows me the last page with the odd behavior.

To reproduce:

1. [Go to Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=161819063969990_265261610292401/comments?limit=2)
2. Click Get Access Token ("read_stream" scope is required)
3. Click submit

Then try to page though all results...

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug confirmed by a Facebook Platform Team member on December 9, 2013 at 8:08pm and then marked as solved on March 18 at 7:45am.

[Bug on Facebook Support](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/723945927635291/)

Now fixed.